# Pandas' apply method

Tags: python, pandas

Does the python pandas `apply()` method work in place? For example, the following code:

```
t = [[10,15], [30,40]]
tt = pd.DataFrame(t, columns=['a', 'b'])
print tt

def func(x):  
#     print '\n\nRunning function on Row', x.name

    if x.name == 1:
        for idx, val in x.iteritems():
#             print idx, val
            x[idx] *= 2

        return x

tt.apply(func, axis=1)
print '\n\n',tt
```

Produces this output:

```
    a   b
0  10  15
1  30  40


    a   b
0  10  15
1  60  80
```

I don't quiet understand why.  If I set `tt = tt.apply(func, axis=1)`, I get an incorrect result.  This makes me think that the `apply()` method works in place, but in other instances, it doesn't, and I actually need to do `new_df = df.apply(func, axis=1)`.  In which scenarios does the `apply()` method work in-place, and in which does it return a new `Series` or `DataFrame`?

Comment: You should consider a func that is passed to apply that simply makes some calculations and returns either a scalar or array like structure to avoid ambiguous behaviour, using apply to modify a df in place is not going to work in practice as especially if you iterating row-wise yet wanting to mutate the df row-wise

Comment: Generally speaking the answer is that `apply` is NOT in place but you made this overly complicated.  Generally you would use `iteritems` OR `apply`, not both.  In this case, you have no need to use `iteritems` in addition to `apply`.  In fact, just do this:   `tt.iloc[1,:] * 2` or  `tt.iloc[1,:] *= 2`

Comment: @JohnE: above is a simple example to a much more complicated function.  My actual function is not a simple `multiply by 2`.  It does other things, and uses the `index` of the `Series` as an input as well.  Really I plan to have a second function which acts on every element in the `iteritems()`.  Perhaps I should use two `iteritems()` instead of `apply`.

Comment: Generally speaking, don't use `iteritems` or `iterrows` if you can help it (and it's rare you really need them).  You're almost certainly better off with `apply` than any of the `iter`-options, and there are often better options than apply.  I realize it's an artificial example, but still...  don't do it!  And consider posting a more realistic (but still simple) example if you want more specific advice.

Comment: @JohnE: Okay, to be a little more specific, I want to run a function on every element in my DataFrame.  I can do that with `applymap`, but the caveat is that one of the arguments ot the function (or one of the things the function needs to know) is the column name.  e.g., the column name is a date, and I'm looking to do calculations based on that date.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @JohnE: Just to follow up, maybe I can iterate over columns and use `map` on each element.  The only issue is how do I feed in the column name to the function? e.g., `for col in df: df[col].map(func)` .. I need to feed `func` the column name as well.

Comment: That should work as far as I can tell.  If not, I'd suggest making up a new and specific question (new post, don't edit this).  Just do it of the style: "I want to do x, and here is what I tried so far".